# Failed to connect: 0 push notification

Tags: php, ios, api, codeigniter

When i execute the below code it is getting

> Failed to connect: 0

1) My path to .pem file is correct.Below is the code which i executed. Iam completely new for this dono wats happening in the code.

I am placing the code below

```
$deviceToken = '44fb58e8011392a1569ddc73ff96d028b5d78739258678455a16abf4e55fa1c1';
//$deviceToken = '44fb58e8011392a1569ddc73ff96d028b5d78739258678455a16abf4e55fa1c1';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'zFaMRvDh7vGTPqh3k+72uz0SzOh3knVZc99OPqkJ3llbYWbpQnRNAKY7TGJu7kg8';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Thank you for Trying Arial 1. Do not forget to enter your feedback to earn TNB points within 10 days';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'http://dev.trynbuyindia.com/ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
```

Comment: http://dev.trynbuyindia.com/ck.pem is this correct

Comment: you can click and check the pem file over there !!!!!

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/apns-php/issues/detail?id=1 check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dev.trynbuyindia.com/ck.pem is this correct..???

Put your certificate in local machine same folder from where you are running php script and change its path in the script

Comment: Mokujin, if you click the link dev.trynbuyindia.com/ck.pem you can see the pem file right. In my local also it is telling 'Failed to connect: 0'. Pls help me !!!!!!!!!

Comment: please give full path of the local ck.pem  like this Users/usersName/Desktop

Comment: I am using ubuntu, created test folder placed files in that and given path /var/www/test/ck.pem still getting same message!!!!

Comment: Please see this link i am getting some errors  dev.trynbuyindia.com/cron/product_feedback_token_post

Comment: please check this link and also check your .pem file is corrupted or no here everything is explained step by step
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: hey please don't mind you have to google it for resolving these issues please copy past in google and try to find answer yourself by which you can learn a lot

Comment: Mokujin its working problem is with $passphrase i changed it to $passphrase = 'welcome01'; then its working

Comment: ok great and try to solve problem from your end. It will increase your learning ability

Answer (score 2):

Use the full path where your PEM file located it may be like this supposei have keeped my PEM file in model directory then my path would be like this

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/var/www/abc/testws/public_html/WebService/application/models/ck.pem');
```

It is working for me.